# UIScrollView on scroll update method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

is there a method / possibility to run a function when the scrollview is scrolling?

i found scroll start and scroll end solutions but nothing like a onIsScrolling ...

is there a built in solution? or whats the best workaround (nstimer)?

thanks
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIScrollViewDelegate` provides the following:

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

in particular:

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
```

Comment: thanks. i will try to implemnt it. after that i will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the scrollViewDidScroll tip.
heres the implemtation sample:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController  <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIScrollView    *theView;
}

@end
```

in .m file:

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    theView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:
CGRectMake(0, 10, 300, 300)];
    theView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:theView];

    theView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 500); 
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL YOUR BOAT");
}
```